# PowerMock + Java + Groovy

Tags: java, junit, groovy, mockito

Крашиться при попытке собрать проект. Если закомментировать строчку в тесте: @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class), то работает. Но тесты по понятным причинам не выполняться как надо.
Вот лог ошибок:

```
org.gradle.internal.service.ServiceCreationException: Could not create service of type ClassLoaderRegistry using GlobalScopeServices.createClassLoaderRegistry().
at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryMethodService.invokeMethod(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:741)
at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.create(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:695)
at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:537)
at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:577)
at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.applyConfigureMethod(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:217)
at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.findProviderMethods(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:178)
at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.addProvider(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:316)
at org.gradle.internal.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder.build(ServiceRegistryBuilder.java:52)
at org.gradle.testfixtures.internal.ProjectBuilderImpl.getGlobalServices(ProjectBuilderImpl.java:93)
at org.gradle.testfixtures.internal.ProjectBuilderImpl.createProject(ProjectBuilderImpl.java:76)
at org.gradle.testfixtures.ProjectBuilder.build(ProjectBuilder.java:99)
at org.gradle.testfixtures.ProjectBuilder$build$0.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:117)
at com.company.gradle.plugins.PluginTest.createProject(PluginTest.groovy:16)
at com.company.gradle.plugins.PluginTest.testMakingPatch(PluginTest.groovy:54)
at com.company.gradle.plugins.PluginTest$testMakingPatch$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
at com.companyk.gradle.plugins.PluginTest.testMakingPatch(PluginTest.groovy:73)
at com.company.gradle.plugins.PluginTest$testMakingPatch.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
at com.company.gradle.plugins.PluginGITTest.testMakingPatchGIT(PluginGITTest.groovy:71)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:68)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:310)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:89)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:97)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:294)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:127)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:82)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:282)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:87)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:50)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:207)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:146)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:120)
at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:122)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:106)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:59)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:112)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.execute(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:56)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(JUnitTestClassProcessor.java:66)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:51)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:109)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:364)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.service.ServiceLookupException: Could not load implementation class 'org.apache.xerces.jaxp.datatype.DatatypeFactoryImpl' for service 'javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory' specified in resource 'jar:file:/C:/gradle-2.13/lib/plugins/xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar!/META-INF/services/javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory'.
at org.gradle.internal.service.ServiceLocator.findServiceImplementations(ServiceLocator.java:114)
at org.gradle.internal.service.ServiceLocator.findFactoriesForServiceType(ServiceLocator.java:74)
at org.gradle.internal.service.ServiceLocator.findFactory(ServiceLocator.java:64)
at org.gradle.internal.service.ServiceLocator.getFactory(ServiceLocator.java:53)
at org.gradle.internal.classloader.DefaultClassLoaderFactory.makeServiceVisible(DefaultClassLoaderFactory.java:113)
at org.gradle.internal.classloader.DefaultClassLoaderFactory.createFilteringClassLoader(DefaultClassLoaderFactory.java:80)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultClassLoaderRegistry.restrictToGradleApi(DefaultClassLoaderRegistry.java:45)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultClassLoaderRegistry.<init>(DefaultClassLoaderRegistry.java:36)
at org.gradle.internal.service.scopes.GlobalScopeServices.createClassLoaderRegistry(GlobalScopeServices.java:163)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.invoke(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:426)
at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.access$1200(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:62)
at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryMethodService.invokeMethod(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:739)
... 73 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Implementation class 'org.apache.xerces.jaxp.datatype.DatatypeFactoryImpl' is not assignable to service class 'javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory'.
at org.gradle.internal.service.ServiceLocator.findServiceImplementations(ServiceLocator.java:110)
... 89 more
```

Пытался сделать, как предлагают тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8179399/javax-xml-parsers-saxparserfactory-classcastexception , но ошибка сохранилась.
Если отслеживать по коду, то последняя строка, из которой идёт вызов - это:

```
 Project project = ProjectBuilder.builder().build()
```

Это из

```
import org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException
import org.gradle.testfixtures.ProjectBuilder
```

Кто чем может помочь?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Данная проблема была актуальная для старых версий PowerMock и в библиотеки Mockito в связке со Spock-ом.

Да данный момент можно использовать моки, которые есть в Spock: https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.0/interaction_based_testing.html

Также новые версии PowerMock-а можно использовать без проблем со Spock-ом: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19493690/using-powermock-with-spock